# Person Re-identification across Multiple Camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I want to re-identify persons across multiple camera. Currently i am using histogram as identity feature to identify person across camera but it is not enough.I want to add more identity feature  to identify persons. I have an idea for this and just want to verify either it would work or not. So, what i am planning to do it that. i will calculate the displacement in x and y coordinate made by the persons calculated from each camera. And Since For the same person, the x and y coordinate displacement will always be same  for the same person  no matter from what angle the camera is shooting the person. I want to use  displacement quantity as another identity feature to re-identify person across camera.

What I wanted to know either this approach work or not: will the displacement made by the same person be equal across multiple camera( camera are not placed  directly in front  or in side way such that  x coordinate or y-coordinate displacement will be 0)..?

Comment: depends on the perspective if I understand right what you meant by "displacement made by the persons"

Comment: When you say "person" do you mean a whole body or a face? When you say "the x and y displacement will always be the same for the same person no matter from what angle the camera is shooting"---well, not exactly. I think you mean if they walk around of course they can only walk on the ground plane, which is true, but those won't be the x and y coordinates you see on the images. You'd need to track them relative to the ground plane, which would require knowing their height or having stereo or depth images.

Comment: displacement means change is x and y coordinate values between successive frames and taking the average to get the  average dispalcement

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds can you please elaborate  what you meant by relative to ground plane means.

Comment: If I am wrong, would you please suggest what should I do to make re- identification more accurate except for using color histogram  features. I want to do as much less camera calibratio task as I can